# How can I use the COM object "VirtualPC.Application" to automate Windows Virtual PC from c#

Tags: virtualization, virtual-pc

I've read that Windows Virtual PC comes with a COM interface (VirtualPC.Application).
I've read blogs about how to use it from Powershell. But how can I use it from c#? Specifically, is there a Primary Interop Assembly (PIA) that I can use in c# to get intellisense in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Export the COM wrapper with:

  tlbimp c:\windows\system32\vpc.exe /out:\vpc.dll
- Add a reference to the generated dll: vpc.dll
- Create the object and use it from C#: `var vpc_obj = new vpc.VMVirtualPCClass();`